Domain and subdomain ownership question regarding website names
I am curious what the legal ownership is around websites such as meta.stackexchange.com and meta.com considering they are both titled the same. I understand the legal definition of a word is not something that can be held and it depends on the context.
This is something I would like to use as an example when talking about Intellectual Property Portfolios and trademark/patent law with Information Technology students. For example when establishing a new website, how would a person go about researching if one is already an existing trademark or if it would be possible to have that domain? Obviously you could not take the same exact site, but could facebook.stackexchange.com exist?
Is there any publicly available filing that I could use to guide this discussion? Do any news articles exist in Wired or online blog posts related to this topic? The only news I can find related to this type of thing I can understand is with the Roller Derby and Baseball teams in Cleveland (https://www.wkyc.com/article/sports/mlb/cleveland-guardians/cleveland-guardians-baseball-club-amicable-resolution-lawsuit-roller-derby-team/95-fb260fa2-c3c6-4444-be14-ecba2ae89e4e).

"but could facebook.stackexchange.com exist?" note that https://facebook.stackoverflow.com (still) exists (some history).


how would a person go about researching if one is already an existing trademark

One can search the trademark database in the relevant jurisdiction.

could facebook.stackexchange.com exist?

facebook.stackexchange.com could exist in principle. There are other trademarked product names that are used as subdomains for product-specific Stack Exchanges:

https://arduino.stackexchange.com (trademark)
https://magento.stackexchange.com (trademark)
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com (trademark)


Just to add a counterexample, Lego.SE has been requested by The Lego Group to change the site name (and thus including the subdomain).
